# Populate textbox using knockout "data-bind=click"

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I wonder if you could help. Just starting using KnockoutJS and I have a problem with populating textboxes based on a selected . I am sure this is very obvious to the well-trained eyes but I can't seem to locate the cause of the problem. Below is my implementation.

```
public class RoleViewModel
{
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationID { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }

}

public class RoleIndexViewModel
{
    public List<RoleViewModel> RolesList { get; set; }
    public RoleViewModel Rvm { get; set; }
}
```

Index.cshtml below

```
@model ExpensesOrganiser4.ViewModels.RoleIndexViewModel

@section scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    <script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Application/role.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        RoleVM.ViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));
    </script>
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rvm.RoleName)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rvm.Description)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rvm.ApplicationName)</th>

   </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.RolesList) {
    <tr data-bind="click: GetSelectedRole" id="updtr">
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoleName)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ApplicationName)</td>
    </tr>
}
</table>

<table data-bind="visible: ReadOnlyMode">
<tr>
    <td><label for="RoleID">Role ID:</label></td>
    <td><input data-bind="value: RoleID()" type="text" id="RoleID" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="RoleName">Role Name:</label></td>
    <td><input data-bind="value: RoleName()" type="text" id="RoleName" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="Description">Role Description:</label></td>
    <td><input data-bind="value: Description()" type="text" id="Description" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="ApplicationName">Application:</label></td>
    <td><input data-bind="value: ApplicationName()" type="text" id="ApplicationName" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Definition for Knockout

```
var RoleVM = {
EditFields: ko.observable(false),
ReadOnlyMode: ko.observable(true),
DisplayEditRoleButton: ko.observable(true),
DisplayUpdateRoleButton: ko.observable(false),
RoleID: ko.observable($("#RoleID").val()),
RoleName: ko.observable($("#RoleName").val()),
OriginalRoleName: ko.observable($("#RoleName").val()),
Description: ko.observable($("#Description").val()),
OriginalDescription: ko.observable($("#Description").val()),
ApplicationName: ko.observable($("#ApplicationName").val()),
OriginalApplicationName: ko.observable($("#ApplicationName").val()),
MessageBox: ko.observable(""),
SelectedRow: ko.observable(),
GetSelectedRole: function (roleData) {
    RoleVM.RoleID(roleData.RoleID);
    RoleVM.RoleName(roleData.RoleName);
    RoleVM.Description(roleData.Description);
    RoleVM.ApplicationName(roleData.ApplicationName);
}
};

function roleData(data) {
this.RoleID = ko.observable(data.RoleID);
this.RoleName = ko.observable(data.RoleName);
this.Description = ko.observable(data.Description);
this.ApplicationName = ko.observable(data.ApplicationName);
}


ko.applyBindings(RoleVM);
```

When I click on the , I get the following in the textbox

```
function c(){if(0<arguments.length){if(!c.equalityComparer||!c.equalityComparer
(d,arguments[0]))c.I(),d=arguments[0],c.H();return this}a.U.La(c);return d}"
```

I know if I call an observable, I need to call it as a function but when I did the following, the textbox contains empty string.

```
GetSelectedRole: function (roleData) {
    RoleVM.RoleID(roleData.RoleID());
    RoleVM.RoleName(roleData.RoleName());
    RoleVM.Description(roleData.Description());
    RoleVM.ApplicationName(roleData.ApplicationName());
}
```

Any advice is deeply appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What do you want to happen when you click on a row?  Is it supposed to then fill out the read only section with that data from the clicked row?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where the data in your current solution can come from so I've made a couple of adjustments.

Firstly I recommend following the pattern of using a function for viewmodels of any complexity as it tends to make things easier.

```
var RoleVM = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.EditFields = ko.observable(false);
    self.ReadOnlyMode = ko.observable(true),
    self.DisplayEditRoleButton = ko.observable(true),
    self.DisplayUpdateRoleButton = ko.observable(false),
    self.RoleID = ko.observable($("#RoleID").val()),
    self.RoleName = ko.observable($("#RoleName").val()),
    self.OriginalRoleName = ko.observable($("#RoleName").val()),
    self.Description = ko.observable($("#Description").val()),
    self.OriginalDescription = ko.observable($("#Description").val()),
    self.ApplicationName = ko.observable($("#ApplicationName").val()),
    self.OriginalApplicationName = ko.observable($("#ApplicationName").val()),
    self.MessageBox = ko.observable(""),
    self.SelectedRow = ko.observable(),
    self.GetSelectedRole = function (roleId, roleName, description, applicationName) {
        self.RoleID(roleData.RoleId);
        self.RoleName(roleData.RoleName);
        self.Description(roleData.Description);
        self.ApplicationName(roleData.ApplicationName);
    }
};
```

You would bind this as follows:

```
ko.applyBindings(new RoleVM());
```

Then you can call `GetSelectedRole` using a wrapper function so that you can pass your data in using some Razor.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.RolesList) {
    <tr data-bind="click: function () { GetSelectedRole(@item.RoleID, @item.RoleName, @item.Description, @item.ApplicationName) }" id="updtr">
        <td class="role-name">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoleName)</td>
        <td class="description">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</td>
        <td class="application-name">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ApplicationName)</td>
    </tr>
}
```

In your solution you have `GetSelectedRole` bound to the click event of the row.  When the click event is fired it calls `GetSelectedRole` with two parameters, data (your viewmodel) and eventArgs.  You have a function called `rollData` which is never called, as it is hidden by the parameter of the same name inside `GetSelectedRole`.  Therefore you are setting your viewmodel's observable values to the observable itself.  So in essence you have a nested observable, so when you are trying to get the observable value it is returning you another observable which when converted to string shows you the observable wrapper function which you see in your text box.

Comment: thanks. I was thinking along the same line. The problem could be masked by the fact that I declared the view model as object laterals rather than function. I will change it to function declaration. However, I would still like to know the cause of the original problem.

Comment: In this case, how can I get the value of the nested observable? Or is there a better way of implementing without using nested observable?

Comment: So I'd implement it the way I wrote it in the original answer because there isn't a way of getting knowledge of which row you are in.  In your code you could change `RoleVM.RoleID(roleData.RoleID);` to `RoleVM.RoleID(roleData.RoleID());` and it wouldn't nest your observables but the values wouldn't change either.  If you really wanted to get the sort of native knockout functionality you appear to be after you may want to drop the MVC view binding in favour of using knockout entirely.

Comment: I was making changes according to your suggestion and it works. I excluded the `function roleData()` method. However, then I change to `data-bind=click: function (data) { GetSelectedRole(data) }` I get the `function c()...`.

Comment: `data-bind=click: function (data) { GetSelectedRole(data) }` is the same as `data-bind=click: GetSelectedRole`, what do you think is in that data parameter?  It contains your whole knockout viewmodel.

Comment: If it contains the knockout viewmodel, shouldn't it return a value if I do `data.RoleName()`? Unless `self.RoleName  = ko.observable($("#RoleName").val());` observable is incorrectly defined. `#RoleName` refers to the textbox whose value should be populated by the selected row and by default, an empty string. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You seem to be confusing your ASP.NET MVC viewmodel with your knockout viewmodel. Your knockout viewmodel has no knowledge of which row has been selected, only that a row has been selected.  You need to add your own logic.  The data that you are getting in GetSeletedRole(data) is not going to be useful to you, it is simply your knockout viewmodel which you have access to anyway.

Comment: I am confused, full stop! LOL. To clarify, in this scenerio, the "data" refers to the knockout viewmodel. I think I am getting what you said about using Knockout binding entirely, ie, `<tbody data-bind="foreach: roles">` , so that the 'GetSelectedRole' will refer to each of the role rather than the entire knockout viewmodel.

Comment: Yes using the foreach binding is what I was talking about but it would basically mean rewriting your whole UI layer!

Comment: Never mind! Part of the learning experience. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it like this

```
data-bind="click: GetSelectedRole.bind($data)"
```

Also change your function using `this`

```
GetSelectedRole: function (roleData) {
    this.RoleID(roleData.RoleID);
    this.RoleName(roleData.RoleName);
    this.Description(roleData.Description);
    this.ApplicationName(roleData.ApplicationName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this (no pun intended). No difference. I still get the "function c()..." populated in the textboxes.

Comment: try removing brackets `text:RoleID` instead of `text:RoleID()`

Comment: "text: RoleID" or "value: RoleID"? Currently, I set it as "value:". No difference. When I changed to "text:", I get the following error     "Uncaught NoModificationAllowedError: Failed to set the 'innerText' property on 'HTMLElement': The 'input' element does not support text insertion."

Comment: When I changed to "text:", I get the following error "Uncaught NoModificationAllowedError: Failed to set the 'innerText' property on 'HTMLElement': The 'input' element does not support text insertion."

Comment: sorry on input it should be `value:RoleID`